# Using `.vue` files with latest browsers that support import/export

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Chrome 60 and latest Firefox with flags have support `import/export` directives. I would like to use `.vue` files without NodeJS, but I can't figure out how to do it.

`import/export` works fine with `.js` files, but when I am trying to do it with `.vue` I am getting fail.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

    <script type="module">  
        import {myc} from './c.vue';
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

for start I tried to place in `c.vue` next code:
    `export const myc = "ccc";`

But I got error: `GET http://localhost:8082/c.vue`.

Is it's possible to place there content like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome!'
    }
  },
  components: {}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Support for `import/export` doesn't mean those browsers also support `.vue` files. VueJS is a custom framework, not official technology in any sense.

Comment: Is there any hacks to get it work?

Comment: Can't you use webpack / browserify? Afaik those are built to solve your problem, and they don't require latest browsers or flags.

Comment: I can, but I really do not like NodeJS and other overhead.

Comment: So you'd rather use hacks and beta browsers to get this to work...? Sorry, no.

Comment: You can't run `.vue` files directly in a browser, simply because you need to import a JavaScript object and not a combination of HTML, JavaScript and CSS in HTMLish way (like a vue file). You have two options: either don't use vue files and use Vue.js in the default way or you use webpack or any other buildtool which converts your vue files to a regular JavaScript (etc.) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, even modern browsers are unable to read .vue files, and that's very unlikely to change in the future. So you should should use some build tool to convert .vue to .js. For bundle solutions, see the other answers.

If for some reason you don't want to bundle them (the only serious reason I can see for it is for fun & test / pure electron release, actually, but anyway), I may have another solution.

I didn't tested it for your particular use case (native import/export in browser), but I wrote [a module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-vueify2) using vueify to convert .vue files into .js, without bundling them, using gulp. It should probably work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to process `.vue` files you need [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) or [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify), which essentially turns them into a js object for you to import. They're built specifically for use with webpack and browserify so you need to use one of those to use `.vue` files.

I know you said you don't like the overhead but the [vue-cli webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) can have you going in minutes.